# Python Pandas : Convert multiple rows into single row, ignoring NaN's

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` similar to the one mentioned below,

```
 Age    Sex    Name ....
 12     NaN    NaN
 NaN    Male   NaN
 NaN    NaN    David
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe with one row, ignoring the NaN's and merging them

```
 Age    Sex    Name
 12     Male   David
```

How to do this is Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` to combine all `columns` after `.dropna()` and `.reset_index()` like so:

```
pd.concat([df[col].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df], axis=1)
```

to get:

```
    Age   Sex   Name
0  12.0  Male  David
```

Comment: I get Attribute error while trying this.. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 3):

Another method is to [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a lambda that calls [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.first_valid_index) to return the first valid row value:

```
In [246]:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.first_valid_index()]))

Out[246]:
    Age   Sex   Name
0  12.0  Male  David
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nasty. Pandas wont do automatic reshape of index ;/. So You have to do in with few operations. Dunno which one is best:

```
import numpy as np,pandas as pd

df= '''
 12     NaN    NaN
 NaN    Male   NaN
 NaN    NaN    David'''

df = np.array(df.split())

df.shape=(3,3)

df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns='Age   Sex   Name'.split())
df.replace('NaN',np.nan,True)

def func(x):
    x.dropna(inplace=True)
    x.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    #s=pd.Series(vals,index=range(vals.shape[0]))
    #print vals.shape
    #print x.shape
    return x

def func1(x):
    x=x.dropna().values
    idx=range(x.shape[0])
    x=pd.Series(x,index=idx)
    #print vals.shape
    #print x.shape
    return x

def func2(x):
    idx=x.first_valid_index()
    x=x[idx]
    x=pd.Series(x)
    return x

print '#'*20
print df
print '#'*20
print 1,df.apply(func,axis=0)
print '#'*20
print 2,df.apply(func1,axis=0)
print '#'*20
print 3,df.apply(func2,axis=0)
print '#'*20
print 3,pd.DataFrame({colId: df[colId].dropna().values for colId in df})

'''
output:

####################
   Age   Sex   Name
0   12   NaN    NaN
1  NaN  Male    NaN
2  NaN   NaN  David
####################
1   Age   Sex   Name
0  12  Male  David
####################
2   Age   Sex   Name
0  12  Male  David
####################
3   Age   Name   Sex
0  12  David  Male

'''
```